# stm32f4-tls and freertos

Tags: stm32, freertos, lwip

I want to use TLS on lwip using modbus tcp applications. But when I choose the mbedtls on CubeMx, I couldnt select lwip. If I use the Freertos, than I can selecect both of them. But I dont want to use FreeRTOS how can I use lwip-tls together ? In the lwip website https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp__tls.html I found the raw api tls documents. Is it possible to use together and how can I use together ?